# Trigger onchange event by injecting a script onto page

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am trying to run js on a page to auto fill this option box (drop down).

```
<td class="fd_value Short"><select class="suptabde" name="F2156" id="F2156" size="1" onchange="selChg(2156);">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="844">Access Management</option>
<option value="1086">Application Amendment</option>
<option value="846">Equipment Request</option>
<option value="1087">Miscellaneous</option>
<option value="1085">System Amendments</option>
</select>

</td>
```

Here is the Js:

```
javascript:function E(){ f0=document.forms[0];
f0['F2156'].value='844';
}E()
```

This fills the option on the page but I need also to deal with the 'onchange'. How is this done by adding to the above js?

Comment: You need to show some more code.

Comment: Post edited with additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a bookmarklet 
That makes more sense

```
javascript:(function(){ var s0=document.forms[0]['F2156']; s0.value='844';s0.onchange();})()
```

the

```
javascript:(function(){})()
```

is executing without having to name the function

You can write it with newlines, they are ignored:

Note the /* comments */ are closed

```
javascript:(
  function(){ 
    var f0=document.forms[0],
        s0=f0['F2156']; 
    s0.value='844';
    s0.onchange();
    /* Next field */
    setTimeout(function() {
      f0['F10'].value='My text added here';
    },1000); /* one second later */
  }
)()
```

Comment: Works great! Can I run several of these in sequence a single bookmarklet?

Comment: You mean on the same select? Perhaps with a timeout. On different ones? Yes

Comment: On different selects, yes a timeout would be useful also.

Comment: You can add whatever you want to a bookmarklet as long as the page does reload

Comment: How do I add a timeout into the solution you gave? Or would it be a separate function?

Comment: For example `javascript:(function(){ var s0=document.forms[0]['F2156']; s0.value='844';s0.onchange(); setTimeout(function(){document.forms[0].submit()},1000)})()`

Comment: I have a textbox on the page I wish to fill also after the timeout. HTML is <textarea class="suptabde" name="F10" id="F10" style=""></textarea> Would my JS look like this? :   javascript:(function(){ var s0=document.forms[0]['F2156']; s0.value='844';s0.onchange(); setTimeout(function(){document.forms[0].submit()},1000)})(); function E(){ f0=document.forms[0];
f0['F10'].value='My text added here';
}E()

Comment: I need a time out to run before populating other fields as submitting the select in the example brings in other select options to the page, based on Value 844 ( i.e populates other options drop downs)

Comment: You cannot write one bookmarklet that can handle a submit if the page changes. If it uses ajax you can. You can also attach to the ajax complete if you really want to dig deeper.

Comment: Updated with a setTimeout